# Regex - Exclude some string after matches

Tags: regex

Sample input:

> RegExr was created by gskinner.com, and is proudly hosted by Media
>   Temple. foo("text1" + getStr()) ; foo('text2') ;
>
> var test = "text1; Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. Roll
>   over matches or the expression for details. PCRE & Javascript flavors
>   of RegEx are supported.
>
> foo('text3')
>
> The side bar includes a Cheatsheet, full Reference, and Help. You can
>   also Save & Share with the Community, and view patterns you create or
>   favorite in My Patterns.
>
> Explore results with the Tools below. Replace & List output custom
>   results. Details lists capture groups. Explain describes your
>   expression in plain English.

I want to get string between foo(" and "). I found foo("*") using below regex.

```
/(foo\(.+\))/g
```

I couldn't exclude foo(" and ") (also foo(' ')).

How can I do that?

[image: regex img]

Comment: `foo\(".*?"\)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't want to get foo(" and ")

Comment: Then capture - `foo\("(.*?)"\)`. Or use lookarounds.

Comment: `(?<=foo\([\'\"]).+(?=[\'\"])` million thanks! @WiktorStribiżew